# How to template dynamically generated react code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, templates

I'm currently working on a framework for a web app that a number of developers will be working on. The web app will be in a dashboard style, with individual modules or "views" written in React.

One of the requirements of the framework is that it must ship with a tool that allows developers to automatically generate a new module or "view", so that it creates the files and folders needed and they can get straight to work on the code logic.

An extremely simple flow would be as follows:

1. Developer enters the name of their new module as an argument to a npm script
2. A script runs which creates `[moduleName.js]` and `[moduleName.less]`, links them together, places them in a directory, and writes the generic react code.

I'm now up to the point where I am generating the common react code. Here is what I wrote:

```
function writeBoilerplate(moduleName) {

var jsFileStream = fs.createWriteStream("./src/m-" + moduleName + "/" + moduleName + ".js");
jsFileStream.once('open', (fd) => {
    jsFileStream.write("import React from \"react\"\;\n");
    jsFileStream.write("import Style from \"\.\/" + moduleName + "\.less\"\;");
    jsFileStream.write("\n");
    jsFileStream.write("\n");
    jsFileStream.write("export default class " + moduleName + " extends React\.Component \{\n");
    jsFileStream.write("\n");
    jsFileStream.write("    constructor\(\) \{\n");
    jsFileStream.write("        super\(\)\;\n");
    jsFileStream.write("    \}\n");
    jsFileStream.write("\n");
    jsFileStream.write("    componentDidMount\(\) \{");
    jsFileStream.write("    \}");
    jsFileStream.write("\}");
    jsFileStream.end();
});
```

You can immediately see the problem here, and I stopped before going too far. If I continue on this path, the code will become unreadable and unmanageable.

I want to refactor this to use javascript templates. However, I have never used templating before and I am unsure of how to create a template and use it, or if there are any tools to help.

How can I refactor this code to use a template?

Comment: Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54260725/2592233

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a template library for that. You can try lodash template one, for example: https://lodash.com/docs#template.

Put your boilerplate in a template file, read it and use something like:

```
var compiled = _.template(templateFileContent);
compiled({ 'moduleName': 'mymodule' });
```

Comment: Could you give me an example of how this would look?

Comment: Did you read the example section in the link I sent you? Just read the template from a file with fs module (https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback) and do the same as the examples on lodash.

Comment: Unfortunately that's the only way. There has to be better ways but there are none.

Comment: https://github.com/elviejokike/react-mustache. This one does the same with Mustache templating if you like it better

Answer (score -1):

Check out the [`react-component`](https://marcellino-ornelas.github.io/templates/docs/main/templates/react-component) template from [templates](https://marcellino-ornelas.github.io/templates)!

**Supports:** typescript, storybook, multiple css languages, and more!

Want more? Need it to fit your code better? use the [`copy`](https://marcellino-ornelas.github.io/templates/docs/main/templates/react-component#copy) command and change it to how you want or [create your own template](https://marcellino-ornelas.github.io/templates/docs/main/create-new-template)

Feedback / contributions are welcome!

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I take your negative rating seriously and would love to learn more about your negative experience. In response to your feedback, I have carefully reviewed our documentation page and made enhancements to make it more user-friendly.

Please don't hesitate to leave suggestions, feedback, or issues on GitHub at https://github.com/marcellino-ornelas/templates/issues. I would love to hear your experience 